# Is passing NULL param exactly the same as passing no param

Tags: php, function, parameters, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I'm working with a function whose signature looks like this

```
afunc(string $p1, mixed $p2, array $p3 [, int $p4 = SOM_CONST [, string $p5 ]] )
```

In some cases I don't have data for the last parameter `$p5` to pass, but for the sake of consistency I still want to pass something like `NULL`. So my question, does PHP treat passing a NULL *exactly* the same as not passing anything?

```
somefunc($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4 = SOM_CONST);
somefunc($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4 = SOM_CONST, NULL);
```

Comment: Yes they are the same, because if you pass nothing, memory is not allocated.

Comment: where is the documentation of making signature of function and what is its use

Answer (score 11):

No.  Presumably, the exact signature is:

```
function afunc($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4 = SOM_CONST)
```

and the function uses `func_get_arg` or `func_get_args` for `$p5`.

`func_num_args` will be different depending whether you pass NULL.  If we do:

```
{
    echo func_num_args();
}
```

then

```
afunc(1,2,3,4,NULL);
```

and

```
afunc(1,2,3,4);
```

give 5 and 4.

It's up to the function whether to handle these the same.

Comment: A real example of this with a PHP function:  `substr($str, 1)` vs `substr($str, 1, null)`.  - "If length is given and is 0, FALSE or NULL an empty string will be returned."

Answer (score 7):

No. It is only the same if the parameter's default value is `NULL`, otherwise not:

```
function a($a, $b, $c = 42) {
    var_dump($c);
}

a(1, 2, NULL);
```

prints `NULL`.

So you cannot say it is always the same. `NULL` is just another value and it is not *that* special.

---

Not to mention non-optional parameters: Calling `a(1)` would give you an error (warning) but `a(1,NULL)` works.

Comment: That is true, now I have function eg. doSomething ($a=1, $b=2) { $arr=array($a, $b); } and if I call doSomething(15) it makes result (15,2). If I call doSomething(15, null), I'll get result (15,NULL). Problem is when I need to set only second (or third, fourth, etc. on more complex functions) parameter like doSomething(, 30) which is not possible in php. It must be set to null and then in function must be used coalescing operator.

Answer (score 5):

Passing `NULL` is *exactly* the same as not passing an argument - if the default value is `NULL`, except in the context of the [`func_num_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) function:

> Returns the number of arguments passed
>   to the function.

```
<?php

function test($test=NULL) {
    echo func_num_args();
}

test(); //outputs: 0
test(NULL); //outputs: 1

?>
```

Comment: Emphasis over **"if the default value is NULL"** ([Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4573600/3088045) covers the opposite case)

Comment: It's also different when functions pass by reference like &$matches in preg_match()

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your function signature is incorrect. It is highly recommended in PHP to keep the optional parameters after all the non optional parameters.

At that point, if you need to skip some of the optional parameters, you can provide `NULL` as their values and the function will use their default value. It will be similar to using the null coalesce operator in `$x = $x ?? 12`. This code will set `$x` to `12` only if `$x === NULL`.

Using the number of arguments with `func_num_args()` should not even be mentioned here because no matter what the value of the argument is, if you pass an argument in the function call, then that argument will be noticed by the function. And when it comes to the inner workings of the function, an extra `NULL` argument is just as good as any other value. Your code might need an argument to be `NULL` in order to perform some task.

The only special treatment happens when an optional function parameter is filled with a `NULL` argument.